# Emulate browser in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, polyfills

I have JavaScript code that was written for browser. It uses document, history, navigator and other browser API. I want to run this code in **node.js**. I don't want to display HTMLElements, draw on canvas etc. I just want to run code, emulating xhr requests, fetch, **websockets** etc. Please, list all variables and functions that I need to polyfill. And are there other ways to run browser js in node?

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *draw on canvas etc. I just want to run code, emulating xhr requests, fetch, websockets etc. Please, list all variables and functions that I need to polyfill.* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope . Looks pretty extensive, doesn't it? Please, list all variables *you* need to polyfill.

Comment: There are things like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom but it certainly doesn't cover the entire web API because this would be impractical or impossible. The question isn't specific enough and looks like XY problem There's a good chance that headless browser should be used instead.

Comment: Please build a website for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If might be better if you provide more context or code examples, but the [mock-browser package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser) is built to handle some of the behavior you mention. I'm not sure if it handles websockets, requests, etc, but it should serve as a good starting point.

If you're just trying to list the functions and classes that are available globally on the window, you can try running `console.log(Object.keys(window))`.