# Adapting code that does dom manipulation to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dom, vscode-extensions

An npm package I want to use contains code like this excerpt

```js
    function callback(div, tune, tuneNumber, abcString) {
        var removeDiv = false;
        if (div === "*") {
            removeDiv = true;
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
        if (params.afterParsing)
            params.afterParsing(tune, tuneNumber, abcString);
        if (!removeDiv && params.wrap && params.staffwidth) {
            tune = doLineWrapping(div, tune, tuneNumber, abcString, params);
            return tune;
        }
        renderOne(div, tune, params, tuneNumber, 0);
        if (removeDiv)
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        return null;
    }
```

As you can see it's riddled with DOM manipulation. This is super annoying considering that what it *does* is transform a string to another string (ABC music format to SVG).

I'm actually trying to use it in a vscode extension, which fundamentally makes this a Node app. I've read [Emulate browser in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562654/emulate-browser-in-node-js) and [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) looks quite promising. What concerns me is code like this

```js
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

because it assumes the existence of "ambient" objects like `document`.

- Are libraries like jsdom able to address that kind of problem?
- Is this the "pollution of the global namespace" that I'm endlessly warned about?
- Can it be done (fake the DOM so this sort of code can run without a massive rewrite) and is a library like jsdom the right way to go about it for less demanding cases?

I'm aware that jsdom isn't a comprehensive browser mock so mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are libraries like jsdom able to address that kind of problem?

Yes, JSDom might be the one most suited for this situation.

> Is this the "pollution of the global namespace" that I'm endlessly warned about?

There's no need for global pollution. All you really need is an identifier named `document` in scope at that time. It doesn't need to refer to a `document` on the global object. To do so in JSDom, all you need is:

```
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);
const { document } = dom.window;
// you may also need
// const { window } = dom;

// paste the rest of your code here
```

It's not a full-fledged browser, but it's still pretty intricate and may well suit your needs. Go for it.

Comment: That's the first time since 2006 I got a good answer so fast I'm not allowed to accept it yet!